# Regular expression to proof if a number is dividable by 5 in Java

Tags: java, regex, string

So, I have to write an Regex statement which proofs if a number is dividable by 5 and returns either true or false. So, after some research I found out that any number which ends with a 0 or 5 is dividiable by 5 and therefore I try to match the last digit of the string with either a 0 or 5.

However, it does not seem to work as the method only returns false, although it worked on an online regex checker.

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      
     String[] digits = {"20", "25", "000", "001", "5123456789"};
        for (String s : digits){
            System.out.println("\"" + s + "\"" + " -> " + proof(s));
        }
    
    
    }
        
    public static boolean proof(String s){
        return s.matches("[0|5]$"); // Here is somehow an issue.
    }
}
```

Comment: `matches()` matches the whole string. Try `s.matches(".*[05]$")`.

Comment: @Turing85 I guess pipe `'|'` is not needed. Otherwise, strings like `"1111|"` would match the regular expression.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko true. It's not only "not needed", but actually wrong since it would match sometzing like `"000|"`. Nice catch! Comments will self-destruct shortly.

Comment: @Turing85 So, it should be something like this `s.matches("^([1-9]\\d*)?[05]$")`. A leading *optional group* which starts with a digit from `1` to `9` followed by zero or more digits, and then followed by `0` or `5` at the very end. For `"01115"` it would be evaluated to `false` and `"1115"` it would give `true`.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko then we can make the group also non-capturing and, as was pointed out already, remove `^` and `$`: `"(?:[1-9]\\d*)?[05]"`.

Comment: @user16320675 most probably not :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one of the possible ways to implement this:

```
public static boolean proof(String s) {
    return s.matches("([1-9]\\d*)?[05]");
}
```

Where `([1-9]\\d*)?` matches an optional group of characters (*i.e. it might not be present*) which should start with a digit from `1` to `9` followed by zero or more digits.

#### Note

- Pipe symbol `'|'` is not needed. When you're using square brackets `[]`, you only need to enumerate the symbols you need to match, i.e. `[05]`.
- While using `matches()` regular expression would be applied to the whole string, i.e. neither `^` and the very beginning, no `$` at the very end are not needed.
- ***Disclaimer:*** in my interpretation of the problem statement leading zeros are not allowed. If this requirement is not relevant, then the following regular expression would be sufficient: `"\\d*[05]"`.

To avoid compiling this regular expression at each method call, we can extract it into `static` `final` field. And since you need a `boolean` result it would be convenient to keep it as a [`Predicate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Predicate.html), for that we can make use of Java 11 [`Pattern.asMatchPredicate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#asMatchPredicate())

```
public static final Predicate<String> IS_DIVISIBLE_BY_FIVE =
    Pattern.compile("([1-9]\\d*)?[05]").asMatchPredicate();
```

```
public static boolean proof(String s) {
    return IS_DIVISIBLE_BY_FIVE.test(s);
}
```

`main()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] digits = {"20", "25", "000", "001", "5123456789"};
    
    for (String number : digits) {
        System.out.println(number + " -> " + proof(number));
    }
}
```

*Output:*

```
20 -> true
25 -> true
000 -> false
001 -> false
5123456789 -> false
```

Comment: Would `005` be a valid case? if so your code would return false for it.

Comment: @JorgeCampos If I understood the problem correctly it, should not be valid. If we allow leading zeros, then `"\\d*[05]"` would be sufficient.

Comment: Reason I pointed out is there is nothing on OPs question stating that leading zeros are/aren't allowed, it was mostly on the comments discussion (which OP didn't comment), in fact it is unclear. So out of completion I would suggest adding this detail to your question :)

Comment: By the way, up for teaching OP about Predicates :)

Comment: @JorgeCampos That was a rightful question, and the answer appeared to be a bit one-sided because of the assumption derived from the discussion in the comments, which is not fully preserved. I've updated the mention of other solution to fix that.